# Totally lost whilst trying to make a javascript quiz?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a quiz in Javascript, using Radio Buttons. I want to be able to display the score, and also show the user which questions they answered incorrectly.

Here is my script so far:

```
var numQues = 4;
var numChoices = 4;

var answers = new Array(numQues)
answers[0] = "b";
answers[1] = "c";
answers[2] = "b";
answers[3] = "a";

function getScore(form) {
    var score = 0;
    var currQ;
    var currChoice;


    if(currChoice.checked) {
        if(currChoice.value == answers[i]) {
            score++;
            break;
        }
    }
}

form.scoreOutofFour.value = score + "/4";
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <form name="quiz">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td> 
            <b>1.</b> Example Question 1  <br />
            <input type="radio" name="q1" value="a" /> a) Example answer 1 <br />
            <input type="radio" name="q1" value="b" /> b) Example answer 2 <br />
            <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c" /> c) Example answer 3<br />
            <input type="radio" name="q1" value="d" /> d) Example answer 4<br />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> 
            <b>2.</b>Example Question 2 <br />
            <input type="radio" name="q2" value="a" /> a) Example answer 1 <br />
            <input type="radio" name="q2" value="b" /> b) Example answer 2 <br />
            <input type="radio" name="q2" value="c" /> c) Example answer 3 <br />
            <input type="radio" name="q2" value="d" /> d) Example answer 4 <br />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> 
            <b>3.</b> Example Question 3  <br />
            <input type="radio" name="q3" value="a" /> a) Example answer 1 <br />
            <input type="radio" name="q3" value="b" /> b) Example answer 2<br />
            <input type="radio" name="q3" value="c" /> c) Example answer 3  <br />
            <input type="radio" name="q3" value="d" /> d) Example answer 4 <br />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> 
            <b>4.</b>Example Question 4<br />
            <input type="radio" name="q4" value="a" /> a) Example answer 1  <br />
            <input type="radio" name="q4" value="b" /> b) Example answer 2<br />
            <input type="radio" name="q4" value="c" /> c) Example answer 3 <br />
            <input type="radio" name="q4" value="d" /> d) Example answer 4   <br />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <b><input type="button" value="Get score" onClick="getScore(this.form); readtheCookie();" /> 
            <input type="reset" value="Clear" /></b> 
            <p>
              <b>
            <div id="cookie12"></div></b><br />
            <textarea name="scoreOutofFour" size="15"></textarea>
            <br />  
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what seems to be the issue? It's hard to help not knowing what's wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is a question & answer site, so you‘ll need to actually ask a question to get any useful feedback.

Answer (score 3):

You weren't as far off a solution as you might think.

Have a look at this possible solution, hopefully it will help you onto the right track.

```
var numQues = 4;
var numChoices = 4;

var answers = new Array(numQues);
answers[0] = "b";
answers[1] = "c";
answers[2] = "b";
answers[3] = "a";


function getScore(form) {
    var score = 0;
    var currQ;
    var currChoice;
    var i, j;

    // loop through the number of questions
    for (i = 0; i < numQues; i ++) {

        // build the name of the form element we want to look at by
        // appending the loop number to 'q', on the first loop the value
        // will be 'q1', on the second 'q2' and so on
        var eleName = 'q' + (i + 1);

        // get all the form elements with the name we built above
        // this should get 4 elements (one for each of the selectable answers)
        var answerRadios = form[eleName];

        // loop through the 4 answer radio buttons
        for (j = 0; j < answerRadios.length; j++) {

            // create a variable to store the current radio button, so
            // it is easier to refernce
            var radio = answerRadios[j];

            // now we check that is this radio button is checked (selected)
            // and the value of this radio is the answer (as defined at the top)
            // then we add 1 tot he score
            if (radio.checked === true && radio.value === answers[i]) {
                score += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    // write the score to the html
    form.scoreOutofFour.value = score + "/4";
}
```